# Как записать содержимое файла в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Текстовый файл содержит целое число.

```
file = open('file.txt')
print(int(file))
file.close()
```

Comment: `переменная = int(file.read().strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для открытия файлов лучше используйте конструкцию with as**

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    int_number = file.read()
    print(int_number)
```

Закрывать файл не надо об этом позаботится python